# Icinga change ping check interval from service and http

Tags: ping, icinga

I have Icinga installed on a machine with the basic configuration and we just use the Host Status Detail screen with a big monitor only to know when a machine is down due to network/eletrical problems. But it takes too long to update the ping times (+1min). 
I'd like to know how to **decrease this ping time to 30 seconds** to all machines (just 15 machines) and how to **decrease the refresh display time from the webpage**.

I did play with some values, mainly **interval_length** inside icinga.cfg (60 to 30) but with no effect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

interval_length is a global config item, you should not mess around with that.

if you really want to push values more often into the core, you should consider running that script by yourself, say in 30sec interval, pushing its results into the command pipe as passive check result - which is considered a workaround, but changing your host config object to passive checks only will work then. if your script fails somehow, make sure to enable freshness checks then.

that will be changed in icinga2 config format, which will understand different time formats (and seconds as well). but it's too soon to make promises here, though you can test the first tech preview as announced on icinga.org

Comment: So are you saying that I can't do any of this with Icinga, changing icinga's cfg files, right now?

Comment: I'm saying you cannot do it via active checks, but rather should configure passive service checks in your config, pushing the results in a more frequent interval - that option works, and is used in some of my environments. freshness checks are ofc enabled to see when something did go wrong (no results received in a timely manner, freshness threshold).

Comment: Can you show me how to do this (tutorial link/snippet) ?

Comment: try http://docs.icinga.org/latest/en/freshness.html for the general explaination on freshness checks, as well as the documentation on passive checks and their usage here: http://docs.icinga.org/latest/en/passivechecks.html 

decreasing the check_interval may be reasonably possible with floats too (undocumented as it's dangerous with the current architecture).